# Creating Pylint File

Tags: python

How do I create a *pylint* file?  I've been searching online and only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448731/how-do-i-create-a-pylintrc-file). And when I run the commands in the link in command (DOS) I get an error that `pylint` is not recognized ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed `pylint`? As you can see in the documentation, you can install it using pip with `pip install pylint` from the terminal, https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html.

Now you should be able to use the command, might require a restart of the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should have Python installed and `pip` available at the command line. Assuming you do, you need to install `pylint` with e.g.:

```
python -m pip install pylint
```

`pylint` itself should be installed under the `Lib\site-packages` folder of whichever Python installation is associated with `pip` at the command line (`where pip`). `pylint.exe` will appear under your `Scripts` folder under that same installation.

At this point, `pylint` should be available from the command line. If it isn't, you should add your `Scripts` folder (containing `pylint.exe`) to your environment variables in Windows (don't forget to log out/log in or possibly reboot after this change).

Note that, as mentioned in one of the answers to your linked question, you can generate a new `pylintrc` file with e.g.:

```
pylint --generate-rcfile > pylintrc
```

or similar (i.e. you can use a full path for the output file). Also as noted, you can specify the location of your `pylintrc` file with `pylint --rcfile=...` where `...` is the name or path to your `pylintrc` file. Otherwise, you can drop this file in the current working directory (as `pylintrc` or `.pylintrc`).

If you want an example of a pre-configured `.pylintrc` file, have a look at [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/datawire/quark/blob/master/.pylintrc).